# Start editing first column of NSBrowser

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbrowser

AppKit's `NSBrowser` appears to have a bug where the method `*/
- (void)editItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)select` doesn't work for the first column in the browser. If indexPath is pointing to an item in the first column, nothing happens. There's another evidence to at http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/327335-nsbrowser-edititematindexpath-withevent-select.html.

I've been working on a workaround for that bug. See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to simulate keypresses of the return key, which enters edit mode for a cell, after the cell was selected. Selecting the correct item is left exercise to the reader. Frankly, if you hit the problem above, you've probably already selected the item before.

I only simulate the key press in case where I want to edit the first column, though it'll probably work in other columns as well, but for them I prefer to use the real API, i.e. `editItemAtIndexPath:withEvent:select:`.

So first I check the indexPath's length to see if it's equal to 1. If it is, the following code simulates the press and release of the return key. `self` is an `NSViewController`, so you might need to adjust based on where this code is called from:

```
NSInteger windowNumber = [[self.view window] windowNumber];
NSEvent *keyDownReturn = [NSEvent keyEventWithType:NSKeyDown location:NSZeroPoint modifierFlags:0 timestamp:GetCurrentEventTime() windowNumber:windowNumber context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] characters:@"\r" charactersIgnoringModifiers:@"\r" isARepeat:NO keyCode:36];
NSEvent *keyUpReturn = [NSEvent keyEventWithType:NSKeyUp location:NSZeroPoint modifierFlags:0 timestamp:GetCurrentEventTime() windowNumber:windowNumber context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] characters:@"\r" charactersIgnoringModifiers:@"\r" isARepeat:NO keyCode:36];
[NSApp sendEvent:keyDownReturn];
[NSApp sendEvent:keyUpReturn];
```

Don't forget to `#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>` for `GetCurrentEventTime()`. Took me a while to find this one.